# Were any scenes in Rogue One filmed in Tikal?

Tags: star-wars, film-location, rogue-one

In Star Wars Episode IV, the scenes featuring the Rebel Base on Yavin IV were filmed at the historic Mayan site of Tikal, in Guatemala.

Scenes at the same base appear in Rogue One; were these shot on location at Tikal, or did they simply use inserted backgrounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, according to [Rogue One's IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3748528/locations). It was **not** filmed in Guatemala.

Filming locations include:

- Canary Wharf Underground Station, Canary Wharf, Isle of Dogs, London, England, UK (Death Star)
- Pinewood Studios, Iver Heath, Buckinghamshire, England, UK
- Bovingdon Airfield, Bovingdon, Hertfordshire, England, UK (Scarif)
- Reynisfjara, Iceland (Eadu)
- Gan, Laamu Atoll, Maldives (Scarif)
- Wadi Rum, Jordan (Jedha)

However, stills *may* have been used to create composites for use in green screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, Tikal was the location for Yavin, as in the original Star Wars (representing the same rebel base location).  Dunno why this isn't acknowledged on IMDB or Wikipedia info for Rogue One yet.  It might be that only scenic photography was filmed there and used as a background for scenes filmed in greenscreen studios.  See example still [here](https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--jl1JgQVR--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/uzexhp8hvun0bdddr6s5.png); the background (jungle & temples) is Tikal but the foreground area isn't (they wouldn't cut a huge clearing in the jungle like that at Tikal just for filming).

Comment: Do you have any reference that shows that there was any filming on site, and to what degree? I'd love to be able to say this for certain.

Comment: No, the pictures in rogue one must be cgi, cause there are no temples like that in Tikal.